# follow up field php/html form

Tags: php, html-select

I am trying to create a follow up field for a select drop down menu.

for example, in the first drop down menu, i have ('yes' => 1, 'no' => 2, 'nothing' => 3).
I want the field that comes afterward to change after i hit select one of the options.
for example: if i choose yes, the field following would be a select drop down menu, for no it would be a text area and for nothing it would be nothing.

I have tried some codes for myself and it didn't work because i don't know how to update the following field right after i choose something. i tried something like this:

```
if (select == 1) {
    echo "$select2";
} else if (select == 2) {
    echo "<input type='text' name='textarea1'/>";
}​
```

but i dont know how to make the page update the field...

please help me

Thanks

Comment: Usually, I would submit the form to itself which will create all your fields as $_POST or $_GET variables (depending on the action set in the form tag) and this will give you the ability to load the correct field in php, provided the value from the form post is what you need.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use some JavaScript (although still sonsider @alightd's suggestion for [graceful degradation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript#Degrading_gracefully)). JavaScript will allow you to show/hide whatever followup field you need to based on the Yes/No/Nothing drop down instantly (without refreshing the page). Makes for a better user experience. Would you be open to a JS solution?

Comment: @AymanSafadi I am pretty new to JS, so if you can explain it too, i would be glad to learn new things. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is, you want to use JavaScript to show/hide questions depending on the answer of the previous question. This is called a [decision tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). If you [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20decision%20tree), they will come. You can find a bunch of examples and libraries that do most of the heavy lifting for you.

If you want to build your own, here's an **incredibly** simplistic way of going about this. This is not a scalable solution, but it should give you the basic idea of how it should work.

#### HTML

```
<label>Do you want this?
    <select name="choices" id="choices">
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
        <option value="2">No</option>
        <option value="3" selected>Nothing</option>
    </select>
</label>
<div id="choices-followup">
    <div id="followup1">
        <label>
            How bad do you want this?
            <select>
                <option>Give it to me now!</option>
                <option>Meh...</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id="followup2">
        <label>Why not?<br />
            <textarea></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>​
```

#### JavaScript

```
// Whenever the user changes the value of
// the element with ID "choices", perform
// this function.
$('#choices').on('change', function() {
    
    // Grab the choice value
    var choice = $(this).val();
    
    // Cache the "choices-followup" object.
    // Every time to you call $('anything'), jQuery
    // goes through the entire DOM looking for that
    // object. Prevent this by making the lookup
    // once, and caching the value.
    var choices_followup = $('#choices-followup');
    
    // No matter what the choice, hide all possible
    // follup fields.
    $('div', choices_followup).hide();
    
    // Also, reset their values.
    $('select, textarea, input', choices_followup).val('');
    
    // If this, then that, etc.
    switch(choice) {
        case '1':
            $('#followup1').show();
            break;
        case '2':
            $('#followup2').show();
            break;
    }
});​
```

#### CSS

```
#choices-followup > div { display: none; }​
```